# Perl-Can't call method "next" on an undefined value at

Tags: perl

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem? I keep getting this solution when I run it: `Can't call method "next" on an undefined value at /Users/myname/Documents/TextWranglerRunTemp-renamer11.pl line 12`.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Path::Class;

my $dir = dir( $ARGV[0] );

# Iterate over the content of the directory
while ( my $file = $dir->next ) {

    if ( $file->is_dir() ) {
        print "Is a directory\n";
    }
    else {

        my @split = split /.([^.]+)$/, $file;

        if ( $split[1] eq "pl" || "docx" ) {
            rename( $file, $split[0] . ".perl" ) || die( "Error in renaming" );
        }

        print "Before " . $file . "\n";

        #rename($file, $file.".abc") || die ( "Error in renaming" );

        # Print out the file name and path
        print "After " . $file . "\n";

        #print $file->stringify . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you passing to the program? (`$ARGV[0]`)

Comment: Note that the condition `$split[1] eq "pl" || "docx"` will always be true **no matter what is in `$split[1]`**. You probably meant to write `($split[1] eq 'pl') || ($split[1] eq 'docx')`.

Comment: Don't delete your code. WIthout that, there is no reference to what you are talking about.

Comment: I am going to edit it and repost it! thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5):

That error means this is failing:

```
while (my $file = $dir->next)
```

And it's caused because you're calling `next` on an undefined value - in the case `$dir`.

`dir` always returns an object, except when it is passed a single argument, and that argument is undefined. In that situation, and in that situation only, it returns `undef`<sup>[1]</sup>. This indicates that `$ARGV[0]` is undefined, which indicates that no parameters were passed to the script while one is required.

---

1. Without this special case, `dir(undef)` would be interpreted as `dir('')`, which returns the root directory, and that would be a dangerous way of handling an incorrect input!